# Python2: Using .decode with errors='replace' still returns errors

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, character-encoding

So I have a `message` which is read from a file of unknown encoding. I want to send to a webpage for display. I've grappled a lot with UnicodeErrors and have gone through many Q&As on StackOverflow and think I have decent understanding of how Unicode and encoding works. My current code looks like this

```
try :
            return message.decode(encoding='utf-8')
        except:
            try:
                return message.decode(encoding='latin-1')
            except:
                try:
                    print("Unable to entirely decode in latin or utf-8, will replace error characters with '?'")
                    return message.decode(encoding='utf-8', errors="replace")
```

The returned message is then dumped into a JSON and send to the front end.

I assumed that because I'm using `errors="replace"`on the last `try except` that I was going to avoid exceptions at the expense of having a few '?' characters in my display. An acceptable cost.

However, it seems that I was too hopeful, and for some files I still get a `UnicodeDecodeException` saying "ascii codecs cannot decode" for some character. Why doesn't `errors="replace"` just take care of this?

(also as a bonus question, what does ascii have to do with any of this?.. I'm specifying UTF-8)

Comment: can you paste an example of message? SO widgets are faithful to unicode & other strange stuff so it will make a real [mcve]

Comment: Which line of code do you get the `UnicodeDecodeException` on?

Comment: It's the last line that throws an error. I'll update with the exception trace in a bit.

Comment: see my comment on @bobince's answer if curious about what the issue was

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should not get a `UnicodeDecodeError` with `errors='replace'`. Also `str.decode('latin-1')` should never fail, because ISO-8859-1 has a valid character mapping for every possible byte sequence.

My suspicion is that `message` is already a `unicode` string, not bytes. Unicode text has already been ‘decoded’ from bytes and can't be decoded any more.

When you call `.decode()` an a `unicode` string, Python 2 tries to be helpful and decides to *encode* the Unicode string back to bytes (using the default encoding), so that you have something that you can really decode. This implicit encoding step *doesn't* use `errors='replace'`, so if there are any characters in the Unicode string that aren't in the default encoding (probably ASCII) you'll get a `UnicodeEncodeError`.

(Python 3 no longer does this as it is terribly confusing.)

Check the type of `message` and assuming it is indeed `Unicode`, work back from there to find where it was decoded (possibly implicitly) to replace that with the correct decoding.

Comment: So you're correct, that seems to be what's happening. I had tried to use either encode('latin-1') or decode('latin-1') an each was giving me errors at some point. I just realized the issue was that there's inconsistency with the string being passed in. Sometimes it's unicode, other times it's encoded. So if I used either of those two methods, I'd get `UnicodeEncodeError` or `UnicodeDecodeError` depending on which failed. I fixed it by trying decode then trying encode when that fails, and it seems to work. At least until I find the source of the inconsistent input.

Comment: Official documentation always helps to complete the picture and help me make sense of things. Here it is for `bytes.decode()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode. And for the `errors=replace` parameter: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers.

Answer (score 1):

decode with error replace implements the 'replace' error handling (for **text encodings** only): substitutes '?' for encoding errors (to be encoded by the codec), and '\ufffd' (the Unicode replacement character) for decoding errors

text encodings means A "codec which encodes Unicode strings to bytes."

maybe your data is malformed - u should try 'ignore' error handling where malformed data is ignored and encoding or decoding is continued without further notice.

```
message.decode(encoding='utf-8', errors="ignore")
```