# Unicode Encode Error when opening and reading .txt files with Python on Mac (OSX 10.15.6)

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I wrote the code below and it works fine: it opens a file dialog, I can pick a text file, and it stores the content in two different variables (one for reading the content as one big string and another with line breaks). Then, I perform several operations by calling the variables with no problem. However, when I create a standalone application (with py2app), the app crashes when it has to read the content.
I could trace the error back to a UnicodeError. For example, I tried to import a .txt file and in return the Console error tab displays the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.pyc", line 1913, in ADD_FILE
  File "main.pyc", line 5593, in write
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 172-174: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is the code I wrote for opening the text file:

```
data = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Select Text File', os.getcwd(), 'Text Files (*.txt)')
    if data != ('', ''):
      with open(data[0], 'r', errors='replace') as file:
         data_lines = file.readlines()
      with open(data[0], 'r', errors='replace') as file:
         data_string = file.read()
```

Comment: This error should only occur for a file write, not a read. Are you using Python 2? Perhaps, there's an implicit write going on here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40038844/4159228. Or, maybe py2app introduces implicit writes on reads? Maybe look into the py2app source for the error-generating line.

Comment: I am using Python 3. Thanks, I'll look into it